# logistic mcmc start

Tags: maximum-likelihood, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I am doing logistic regression with MCMC .  What is a good start for MCMC ?

Comment: What is your preferred statistics software or programming language?

Comment: Software -R studio

Comment: I u know R , will glm() function give me the maximum likelihood estimate of beta ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as that point has prior distribution greater than 0, that shoud be perfectly fine. For models complex enough (this one doesn't seem so) it's a good idea to train multiple chains from different starting point, and then check for convergence.

Comment: I know that but I have a question in my programming assignment which explicitly asks a good starting point . How can I explain that maximum likelihood is a good starting point (I read it in somewhere online but without reason )

Comment: Any point that has a good posterior probability is just perfect for starting a chain, any point that's near enough to posterior highest probability region, is still just fine. since posterior probability is proportional to prior and likelihood, maximum likelihood point should have a good posterior probability too. Of course if your data is scarce and your prior is strong, you may as well use maximum prior probability point, for the same reason.

Comment: If this is an assignment, you should add the `self-study` tag and show more input than this. (Starting with the MLE is helpful if only applicable in cases when MCMC is not particularly needed.)